# Gradle plugins DSL: Restriction on declaration location

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a few Gradle scripts that get applied via `apply from: 'my-build.gradle'`. If I use the new plugins DSL as follows in the external build file `my-build.gradle`, it fails with the following error:

```
> startup failed:
  Only Project build scripts can contain plugins {} blocks
  See http://gradle.org/docs/2.3/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block 
  for information on the plugins {} block
```

Looking at the documentation pointed in the error message didn't reveal as to why the restriction is in place. Why is there a restriction on the location of the plugins declaration?

Files for reference below.

1. `my-build.gradle` file:

   ```
   plugins {
       id "net.saliman.cobertura" version "2.2.5"
   }
   ```
2. `build.gradle` file:

   ```
   apply from: "my-build.gradle"

   // Other stuff
   ```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is how you can use plugins in external Gradle files such as your `my-build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.sonarqube.gradle:gradle-sonarqube-plugin:1.1"
    classpath "net.saliman:gradle-cobertura-plugin:2.2.8"
  }
}
// Because this is a helper script that's sourced in from a build.gradle, we can't use the ID of external plugins
// We either use the full class name of the plugin without quotes or an init script: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/init_scripts.html
apply plugin: org.sonarqube.gradle.SonarQubePlugin
apply plugin: net.saliman.gradle.plugin.cobertura.CoberturaPlugin

// rest of my-build.gradle omitted
```

Above I've activated the plugins for [SonarQube](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube) and [Cobertura](https://github.com/stevesaliman/gradle-cobertura-plugin).

Generally, to get the fully qualified class name of your plugin you will have to look inside its `.jar` file.

As for the technical reasons *why* you can't use a `plugins {}` block in an external file, I do not know. It might have to do something with the [following](https://docs.gradle.org/2.9/userguide/plugins.html#plugins_dsl_limitations):

> [...] plugins [need to] be specified in a way that Gradle can easily
> and quickly extract [them], before executing the rest of the build
> script. It also requires that the definition of plugins to use be
> somewhat static.

But [rejoice](https://docs.gradle.org/2.9/userguide/plugins.html#N11AC8):

> Future versions of Gradle will remove this restriction.

Comment: Thanks for the references :) I was aware of the workaround, but a bit puzzled on why `plugins` closure didn't work from an external file.

Comment: How would you use this workaround to apply one of the built-in plugins like `application` or `java-library` ?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar issue recently and it got solved by changing Gradle settings in Intellij as follows:

[image]